# Retrieve a value from the first node in an XML::Nodeset using Crystal

Tags: xml, xpath, crystal-lang

I am using Crystal, and am trying to retrieve the ID of a node in an XML document:

```
<foo ID="bar"></foo>
```

I am using the following code to get to the ID

```
require "xml"
file = File.read("path/to/doc.xml")
xml = XML.parse(file)
xpath_context = XML::XPathContext.new(xml)
nodeset = xpath_context.evaluate("//foo/@ID")
```

If I inspect the nodeset, I get the content I am expecting:

`[#<XML::Attribute:0x1287690 name="ID" value="bar">]`

And `nodeset.class` returns `XML::NodeSet` which has [an instance method `[]`](http://crystal-lang.org/api/XML/NodeSet.html). So I believe I should be able to do this to get the value:

```
node = nodeset[0]
node.value
```

However, when I call `nodeset[0]` I get the following error:

```
undefined method '[]' for Float64 (compile-time type is (String | Float64 | Bool | XML::NodeSet))

    node = nodeset[0]
```

I do not understand why the `[]` method is seeing nodeset as a Float64 when both `inspect` and `class` are seeing it as an `XML::Nodeset`.

What am I missing?

Is it a coincidence that String has a `[]` method, but Float64 does not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you execute `evaluate` the return type is a union type of all the possible values. In this case `XML::NodeSet` is the runtime type (notice the difference with the compile time type).

If you can assure that the return type is always a node set, then you can simply do:

```
nodeset = xpath_context.evaluate("//foo/@ID") as XML::NodeSet
```

But that will raise an exception if the result has a different type.
Another option is do it conditionally:

```
if nodeset.is_a?(XML::NodeSet)
    # use nodeset here without casting, the compiler will restrict the type
end
```

Or even with a `case` statement:

```
case nodeset
when XML::NodeSet
  # ...
end
```

Comment: You can also use the xpath method, and the xpath_nodes (or related names) to avoid the cast (it will be done, but by that method). For example: http://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/fwa

Comment: Ah! I get it. As `evaluate` could return an object of a number of different types, the compiler with work through each of them trying to get a result.

Comment: Thanks @asterite. xpath_nodes looks like a better way to go - but I'm glad I asked the question as it's helped me understand crystal a little better.

Comment: Actually - for my requirement xpath_node is even better.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, here is the code I ended up with, with the help of @asterite and @waj

```
file = File.read("path/to/doc.xml")
xml = XML.parse(file)
node = xml.xpath_node("//foo/@ID")
node.text
```

Note that node.value was wrong too!

Comment: Since we aren't 1.0.0 yet there are many types that change and aren't documented. We hope that once these types are documented it will be easier to find this funcionality :-)